# Execute AND concatenated search on two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, search

I've two tables

```
#keywords
content_id | keyword
-----------+----------
2          | lorem
6          | loremsis
6          | ipsum
6          | dolor

#tags
content_id | tag
-----------+----------
2          | amet
6          | lorem
6          | amet
```

Note, these two tables cannot be merged into one table. I want to execute a search with AND concatenation and with right-side `LIKE` operator. At the moment, the statement for this looks like

```
SELECT content_id FROM (

  SELECT content_id FROM store_keywords
  WHERE keyword LIKE 'lorem%' OR keyword LIKE 'ipsum%'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT content_id FROM store_tags
  WHERE tag LIKE 'lorem%' OR tag LIKE 'ipsum%'

) s1
GROUP BY content_id
HAVING COUNT(*)='2'
```

So what do we get when searching for `"lorem ipsum"`?

```
#keywords
content_id | keyword
-----------+----------
2          | lorem
6          | loremsis
6          | ipsum

#tags
content_id | tag
-----------+----------
6          | lorem
```

That does not fit `HAVING COUNT(*)='2'` which can be fixed by using `>='2'`. So ID `6` is returned, because it contains both terms. But when searching for `"lorem odem"` we get

```
#keywords
content_id | keyword
-----------+----------
2          | lorem
6          | loremsis

#tags
content_id | tag
-----------+----------
6          | lorem
```

which fits `HAVING` clause but does not contain any result for term `"odem"`.

So, does anyone has an approach for a statement with following requirements:

- **all** words of search term have to be found (**AND** concatenated search)
- search is executed on two tables which *can* contain doublets and matching terms in both tables, but also in one table only

Comment: Could not reproduce. I even tried your tables and queries in my database, but got expected results. I don't know how you got yours.

Comment: Please check: (1) that tables contains what you think that they contains (2) That you can reproduce the problem if manually executing queries in mysql (3) That your program executes a query that you think it executes (4) That your program handles results the way it should do it.

Comment: Huh? I don't believe, that you've tried to reproduce the problem in exactly the way I've described it. Did you execute full SQL statement!? When replacing `"ipsum%"` with `"odem%"` in first statement above, I get ID `6` which is not what I want.

Comment: I think I finally realized what you wanted. Try code from my answer.

Comment: "lorem odem" got accepted, because "lorem%" was once in keywords and once in tags, which are 2 occurrences whn counted together (UNION).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still can't understand your description, but looking on your project, you probably want to

*get content_id, which contains both two words from search string, either in keywords or tags*

correct?

Then you need this query:

```
SELECT distinct t1.content_id FROM
(
  SELECT content_id FROM store_keywords
  WHERE keyword LIKE 'lorem%'
  UNION
  SELECT content_id FROM store_tags
  WHERE tag LIKE 'lorem%'
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT content_id FROM store_keywords
  WHERE keyword LIKE 'ipsum%'
  UNION
  SELECT content_id FROM store_tags
  WHERE tag LIKE 'ipsum%'
) t2
ON t1.content_id = t2.content_id
```

Comment: Well, that did the trick, but this is only handy up to three terms, because for every new term has an `INNER JOIN` to be added, doesn't it? Therefor I'll give temporary tables a try (I'll post my actual solution as an answer also)

Comment: Yes. Well, INNER JOIN is pretty fast and memory-friendly (not like cross join or left join), thus it should work well even with several of them, just try it to find reasonable limit

Comment: Also, it might help you a little if you had just one table of `content_id`|`word`|`ENUM_keyword_or_tag`

Answer (score 0):

@David162795 answer will be fine for only some search terms, but in real life there could be a dozen terms, so I'll give temporary tables a try. I think my solution would *not* be really slower than many `INNER JOIN`s. So I add every `content_id` in combination with the search term to the temporary table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE search (
    content_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    term VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (content_id, term)
);

INSERT IGNORE INTO search (content_id, term) SELECT content_id,'lorem' FROM store_keywords WHERE keyword LIKE 'lorem%';
INSERT IGNORE INTO search (content_id, term) SELECT content_id,'ipsum' FROM store_keywords WHERE keyword LIKE 'ipsum%';
INSERT IGNORE INTO search (content_id, term) SELECT content_id,'lorem' FROM store_tags WHERE tag LIKE 'lorem%';
INSERT IGNORE INTO search (content_id, term) SELECT content_id,'ipsum' FROM store_tags WHERE tag LIKE 'ipsum%';
```

Now one could cleanup table from IDs which occurence is less than count of terms

```
DELETE t1
FROM search t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT content_id FROM search GROUP BY content_id HAVING COUNT(*)<2
) t2 ON t1.content_id=t2.content_id;
```

or use that table in `SELECT` directly

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM store_content t1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT content_id FROM search GROUP BY content_id HAVING COUNT(*)>=2
) t2 ON t1.id=t2.content_id;
```